# Centering Vertically an UL inside a DIV

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

i am trying to make a navigation menu inside a 200px x 200px square, this navigation list (UL) 
changes from square (200px) to square in 2 rows, like a table, it has some transitions and a lot more stuff going on, but i don't think that affects the vertically centering i want to accomplish. 
(i've seen the other answes for this question, but they don't fit this specific scenario, line-height doesn't work, etc.) 
these multiple menus are the ones i want to be aligned depending on every element i add, if i just add 1 element then it looks like the center square, of course there is a limit of elements too that can fit on the square, i have a maximum already ( 5 elements ) according to my actual HTML - CSS 


This is what i want to accomplish


[image: http://s29.postimg.org/63xzmm1kn/navelements.png]

the html markup is something like this

```
<div id="table" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="width 100%"> 
                  <div id="row">  
                      <div> 
                          <div class="nav"><ul><li><a href=link...>Element 1</a></li> <!----- this is the navigation menu that is in top of an image---> 
                              <img alt="" src="image.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" /></div> 
                         <div class="nav"><ul><li><a href=link...>Element 1</a></li><li><a href=link...>Element 2</a></li> <!----- this is the navigation menu that is in top of an image---> 
                              <img alt="" src="image.jpg" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;" /></div>
```

I know i am not giving too much info, but i can't really put the code as it is, it's work for a private company, but i hope you understand my scenario, the menu on top of the img it has an RGB alpha transition that makes it appear on top of on :hover, but again, i think the important thing is to align every button vertically like that, withouth recurring to special "fixes" for every different section using "position: relative; top: 30px;" i could do that, but i want to understand and see if i can do it without too much trouble, and adding the elements i want to and get automatically aligned in perfect center.

Thank you so much for your help. 
  (english is not my first language so i hope it is understandable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick for centering something vertically includes two simple steps:

1. Move the content to its top half of its height using `transform: translateY(-50%)`.

   [image]
2. Apply `top: 50%`. The element must be positioned relatively for this to work.

   [image]

There are ofcourse many ways to do this.

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.main-container {
  width: 640px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #0077A3;
  margin: 5px;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 10px;
}
span {
  background-color: #00C430;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Element 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Element 2</span></li>
      <li><span>Element 3</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Element 1</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li><span>Element 1</span></li>
      <li><span>Element 2</span></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Centering in the Unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) approach.

Use HTML like

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Element 1</li>
    <li>Element 2</li>
    <li>Element 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To center `ul` vertically inside `.container`, use

```css
.container:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
}
.container:before, ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #333333;
}
.main-container {
  width: 610px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  background: #0077A3;
}
.container:before {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
}
.container:before, ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #00C430;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Element 1</li>
      <li>Element 2</li>
      <li>Element 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Element 1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>Element 1</li>
      <li>Element 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```